# In android, Can I get a selected text to my Application from Mozilla?

Tags: android, select, text, copy, tooltip

I'm planning to develop english tool-tip dictionary in android.
As I mentioned in the title, is there any way to get a selected(or tapped) text from Mozilla or any other text viewer program to my application??

copying to clipboard is not convinient, so I want to pop up the meaning of word when people select it or tap it..
but I still can't find how to carry out the text.

I only found getSelectionStart() and document.onselectionchange which is used when we get the text of it's own program.

Is there any way to carry out the selected text to other program? and without being rooted.
Please rescue me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access events like this unless it is your own application for security reasons.

If allowed, malicious apps could use this to copy personal details like usernames and passwords